# Argument not allowed with keyof ("Expected 0 arguments, but got 1")

Tags: typescript

Trying to implement a typing where primitive properties are of type `KnockoutObservable<Primitive>` in a recursive/nested way:

```
export type Primitive = string | number | boolean | undefined | null;

export type KnockoutMappedProperty<T> =  T extends Primitive ? KnockoutObservable<T> : KnockoutMappedType<T>;

export type KnockoutMappedType<T> = {
    [Property in keyof T]: KnockoutMappedProperty<T[Property]>;
};

interface KnockoutObservable<T> extends KnockoutSubscribable<T>, KnockoutObservableFunctions<T> {
    (): T;
    (value: T): void;
    /*...*/
}
```

Calling the function without argument compiles:

```
const v1: KnockoutMappedType<{ prop: boolean }> = null;
const propValue: boolean = v1.prop();
```

Passing an argument does not compile as if `(value: T): void;` would not exist in `KnockoutObservable<T>`:

```
v1.prop(true); // Gives compiler error: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1
```

Intellisense tells me that `v1.prop` is of type `KnockoutObservable<true> | KnockoutObservable<false>`. Why is something split into a union type that should simply be `KnockoutObservable<boolean>`?

The following compiles fine again:

```
const prop: KnockoutObservable<boolean> = v1.prop;
prop(true);
```

Why do I need to introduce a variable of type `KnockoutObservable<boolean>`?

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Primitive%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20undefined%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20KnockoutMappedProperty%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%20T%20extends%20Primitive%20%3F%20KnockoutObservable%3CT%3E%20%3A%20KnockoutMappedType%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20KnockoutMappedType%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BProperty%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20KnockoutMappedProperty%3CT%5BProperty%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20KnockoutObservable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(value%3A%20T)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*...*%2F%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20v1%3A%20KnockoutMappedType%3C%7B%20prop%3A%20boolean%20%7D%3E%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0Aconst%20propValue%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20v1.prop()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20prop%3A%20KnockoutObservable%3Cboolean%3E%20%3D%20v1.prop%3B%0D%0Aprop(true)%3B%0D%0Av1.prop(true)%3B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that conditional types distribute over unions as stated in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). While it might not be obvious at first, `boolean` is a union, the union `true | false`. This means that the mapped `prop1` will be of type `KnockoutObservable<true> |  KnockoutObservable<false>`. This means the only callable signature will be the common one, the one without any parameters.

To stop the distributing behavior, you can clothe the type parameter in a tuple (since distribution occurs only over naked type parameters)

```
export type Primitive = string | number | boolean | undefined | null;

export type KnockoutMappedProperty<T> =  [T] extends [Primitive] ? KnockoutObservable<T> : KnockoutMappedType<T>;

export type KnockoutMappedType<T> = {
    [Property in keyof T]: KnockoutMappedProperty<T[Property]>;
};

interface KnockoutObservable<T> extends KnockoutSubscribable<T>, KnockoutObservableFunctions<T>  {
    (): T;
    (value: T): void;
    /*...*/
}

const v1: KnockoutMappedType<{ prop: boolean }> = null;
const propValue: boolean = v1.prop();
v1.prop(true); // ok
```